# Java vs C floating point: "x * x" differs from "pow(x,2)"?

Tags: java, c, floating-point, floating-accuracy

Why is this true? Java appears to produce a result with a small discrepancy when multiplying two floats compared to C and even the Java Math.pow method.

Java:

```
float a = 0.88276923;

double b = a * a;   // b becomes 0.779281497001648  <---- what???
b = Math.pow(a,2);  // b becomes 0.7792815081874238
```

C:

```
float a = 0.88276923;

double b = a * a;   // b becomes 0.7792815081874238
pow(a,2);           // b becomes 0.7792815081874238
```

Update: Per Ed S.'s comment, I have also found that the C behavior changes depending on the compiler. Using gcc it appears to match the Java behavior. Using visual studio (depending on your target platform) it can produce the results seen above or those seen in Java. Ugh.

Comment: http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: Ah, floating point arithmetic. A pure bastion of accuracy and reliability.

Comment: I'm aware that floats are not precise. I would expect, however, for their imprecision to be consistent.

Comment: When I type it into the Windows XP calculator, I get 0.88276923*0.88276923 = 0.7792815134347929 which is even more different.

Comment: You're not compiling the C code with a C++ compiler and therefore using the `float` overloaded version of `pow` are you? [`float pow(float base, float exponent)`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cmath/pow/)

Comment: @AusCBloke: Why yes I am. I compiled with Visual Studio. Update: I just compiled with a gcc and the C results now match the original Java results.

Comment: I did my testing using VS2005 and the C results are the same (actually using the C89 compiler)... until I target x64, in which case the `fld` instruction is dropped in favor of `movss` and you get the java behavior.  Oh the joys of programming.

Comment: @user949300 The closest to `0.88276923` in float precision is **0.882769227**02789306640625 but **0.882769229**999999960334378101834 in double precision. MS calculator do the math in much higher precision and that's why the difference

Comment: MSVC is a C++ compiler, not C, so that may account for the difference. GCC is a C compiler so try with g++ instead

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As pst and trutheality have already wisely noted, C is promoting the `float` to a `double` *before* the multiplication.  Actually, they are promoted to an 80-bit extended precision value when they are  pushed onto the stack.  Here is the assembler output (VS2005 x86 C89)

```
    double b = a * a;
00411397  fld         dword ptr [a] 
0041139A  fmul        dword ptr [a] 
0041139D  fstp        qword ptr [b]
```

**The FLD Instruction**

> The FLD instruction loads a 32 bit, 64 bit, or 80 bit floating point value onto the stack. **This instruction converts 32 and 64 bit operands to an 80 bit extended precision value** before pushing the value onto the floating point stack.

---

Interestingly, if I build to target x64, the `movss` instruction is used and you get a value of `0.779281497001648` as the result, i.e., what you are seeing in your java example.  Give it a try.

Comment: +1. Now, where in the C standard (and don't forget to specify which draft!) is there a vauge statement that can be construed as implementation-defined behavior on two.... ;-)

Comment: @pst: Tried it targeting x64 out of curiosity and you see the java behavior as the `fld` instruction is no longer used (in my setup at least).

Comment: I imagined something sneaky, but not this sneaky. I wish I could give a second vote up.

Answer (score 10):

What Java does for

```
double b = a * a;
```

is multiply `a * a` as a (32-bit) `float` first, and converts the result to a (64-bit) `double` when assigning to `b`.

```
b = Math.pow(a,2);
```

Converts `a` to a (64-bit) `double` first (since the parameters for `Math.pow` are `double, double`) and then squares it.

What is puzzling (to me) is why C seems to cast the `a`'s to `double` first in

```
double b = a * a;
```

<del>Is that in the standard?</del>

<del>**Edit:** I vaguely remember about C not requiring a particular implementation (in terms of how many bits are used) for numbers... is that what's going on here? Are your `float`s 64 bits? (In Java a `float` is always 32 bits and a `double` is always 64 bits).</del>

**Edit:** Both Ed S.'s answer and mark's comment that different compilers give different results indicate that the C results are implementation- and architecture- specific.

Comment: I wonder if there is any compile-time evaluation (optimizing) occurring as well?

Comment: (Although I'd doubt that `sizeof(float) == sizeof(double)` on a modern machine/compiler ;-)

Comment: On my machine they are promoted when pushed onto the stack. See: [The FLD Instruction](http://webster.cs.ucr.edu/AoA/Windows/HTML/RealArithmetica2.html)